# MySQL variable gtid_executed changes frequently

Tags: mysql, global-variables

Is it normal, that the MySQL global variable gtid_executed changes multiple times in a minute?

These MySQL commands were executed in a time range of 10 seconds:

```
mysql> show global variables like 'gtid_executed';
+---------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                                           |
+---------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| gtid_executed | d4eeed2f-6cc7-11e9-aa15-fa163e5318c7:1-26918205 |
+---------------+-------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show global variables like 'gtid_executed';
+---------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                                           |
+---------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| gtid_executed | d4eeed2f-6cc7-11e9-aa15-fa163e5318c7:1-26918206 |
+---------------+-------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show global variables like 'gtid_executed';
+---------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                                           |
+---------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| gtid_executed | d4eeed2f-6cc7-11e9-aa15-fa163e5318c7:1-26918207 |
+---------------+-------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Every time there is a different value! Is that normal?
It is a single node SaaS MySQL RDS instance in a cloud environment.
Thank you kindly in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have activity on the server this is a normal behaviour, as for each new transaction a new `GTID` value is assigned to it incremented by one.

Comment: Yes, that's it! Now I know it. This was causing to freak out our monitoring tool, but now we know ;-)